# get size of button in onCreate()

Tags: android, button

I want to get the size of the button which is placed in the surfaceView on onCreate(). How do I get that?

If I use button.getWidth() in onCreate() I get 0. However, I can get the size of the button in onStart() but that is not what is intended. I understand the reason for this behaviour.

But, in case I want to place another view based on the size of the button in onCreate() of my activity, how do I achieve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can.  You will have to move it later in the code. try doing it in onLayout.  or override the buttons onSizeChanged() to add the other button (but check for any parameters=0 and exit.  it will be called again later)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can get your button width in OnCreate() to get width and height you can use this below method

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
   super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    // Call here getWidth() and getHeight()
}
```